# Upload Videos to Youtube WITHOUT OAUTH

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I am making a program to upload YouTube videos to my clan channel so that I can distribute it to the other clan members and everything is all set...

They open the program, they browse the file, set the title, the privacy and press Upload. DONE
If they want they open the thumbnail changer, browse for the thumbnail press Upload. DONE

It works great!... In my computer, how can I make it that it works for everyone? because everytime I share it with one of the members... it doesn't work because they need to login using OAUTH (to one of their accounts).

Thanks for helping!
I'm coding in C# but that is not relevant at all.. by the way I've already tried older methods present in the API but it returns invalid request.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the YouTube API without Oauth.  If you want to access private user data you need to have the permission of the user who owns the data.

Your only option would be to authenticate your code once and store the refresh token and use it when the others want to access your data.   If you are using Google .net Client library check filedatastore its storing your refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for uploading videos to youtube without OAuth, You only need API key, Username, Password.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet?csw=1#Direct_Upload

Comment: v2.0 which supports username/password is deprecated.